# VLOOKUP on each cell and sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Let's say that I have a row of letters. And I have a table that matches each letter with a number. 
How can I perform a SUM() of all letters?

Example:

```
A    |    G    |    A    |    N    |    G    |    A


A    |    7
G    |    2
N    |    3

Total: 7 + 2 + 7 + 3 + 2 + 7 = 28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate through the range and SUMIFS() to return the value:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B3:B5,A3:A5,A1:F1))
```

[image]

Or you can use the following array formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B3:B5,N(IF(1,MATCH(A1:F1,A3:A5,0)))))
```

The Match returns an array of the relative row to the INDEX which in turn returns the values to the SUM.

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

[image]

If the lookup range is always sorted in ascending order you can use LOOKUP instead of SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(A1:F1,A3:A5,B3:B5))
```

But NOTE the warning, the list MUST be sorted ascending.

[image]